# I just had my driveway sealed, and the fumes are making my house uninhabitable. What can I do?

Tags: driveway, air-quality

I've seen claims about buckets of water, vinegar, and cut onions helping with freshly painted rooms. But that's all. Is there anything I can do to make these fumes go away? Or am I doomed to stay with my in-laws for the indefinite future?

Comment: Are your windows closed?

Comment: Forget all those, a half-faced respirator with organic-vapor/acid-gas cartridges (which are basically activated carbon)

Comment: Just stop breathing, it will only affect you if you breathe.

Comment: I read an article that suggested using a blow dryer (that one normally uses to dry one's hair after showering).  At the end of the article, the author concluded that the primary benefit of doing this is the air movement.  That suggests to me that setting up a fan might help somewhat if the driveway isn't too large.  // I have also seen recommendations to sprinkle with fine sand.

Comment: I think they make a water based sealer .Next time my make less fumes. Not sure of the quality of product .

Comment: How long did the small last?

Comment: It didn't take long to go away once I turned the HVAC back on.

Answer (score 2):

As Tester101 said, first step is isolating your house from them: close doors, windows, garage, and so on.

Next step is dealing with those vapors that do come in.  Have you tried activated carbon filters?  They make ones that fit in your air handler.  These things can absorb amazing amounts of organic vapors.

As for the sealer, it will off-gas the volatile components at a first order rate (I think, someone may correct me), which means it has a half life.  The amount will drop exponentially over time.  It should get better,but there's not much you can do to speed it up.

Comment: Heat will drive off the volatiles.  You will be free of fumes once summer is in full swing.  I suppose if you could find a way to heat the driveway artificially, you could drive off the smell sooner.

Comment: Agreed, heat is the one variable, really.  Not really sure if there's anything you can do besides making sure the sun can hit it cleanly as it will heat up to pretty high temperatures.